# Is there any way in Google Big Query to Left Outer Join one-to-one *without reusing* any row from the right?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, google-bigquery

We have a group of patients in one table and we want to match each of them to a patient exactly like them in another table - but we want pairs of patients so we cannot match a patient to more than one other patient.

Left Outer Joins add every occurrence of a match - which matches patients to every other possible match - so we need some other approach.

We see lots of answers on SO about matching to the first row - but that leaves us with a single patient being matched to multiple other patients - not a pair like we need.

Is there any possible way to create pair matches without duplication between tables in Google Big Query? (Even if it takes multiple steps.)

---

**ADDENDUM**: Here are example tables. **It would be great to see a SQL example using this.**

Here is what is needed.

```
Example Source Tables:

Table A
PatientID     Race     Gender    
   1            A        F
   2            B        M
   3            A        F

Table B
PatientID
   4            A        F
   5            A        F
   6            B        M


Results Table Desired:

Table C
A.PatientID     B.PatientID_Match
    1               4
    2               6
    3               5
```

---

**CLARIFICATION**: Patients in Table A must match patients from Table B. (They cannot match patients in their own table.)

Comment: This should be possible provided that you give logic for _which_ of the possible matches a record should be retained.

Comment: supply a bunch of sample data and expected results. Google Cloud Sql is just maria as they wanted to avoid enterprise mysql pricing and blaze their own trail with it. Other than that, there is no need to mention Google in any of this (as I see it)

Comment: In each table, just assign each patient a rank. Pair each patient in table_a with the patient with the corresponding rank in table_b

Comment: See http://rextester.com/WCBQDE57469

Comment: @Drew We added sample table data.

Comment: @drew Correction - we are doing this on Google Big Query (mistype) which has a variety of extended SQL vocabulary which we wondered might apply

Comment: It's not just left joins - ALL joins exhibit this behavior, because SQL operates on set math.  If there aren't sufficient identifiers to guarantee a 1-to-1 match, I'm a little worried about your attempts to perform this correlation...

Answer (score 2):

```
select      min (case tab when 'A' then patientID end)  as A_patientID  
           ,min (case tab when 'B' then patientID end)  as B_patientID

from       (select  tab
                   ,patientID
                   ,rank()       over (order by     race,gender)                        r
                   ,row_number() over (partition by tab,race,gender order by patientID) rn

            from    (           select 'A' as tab,A.* from A 
                    union all   select 'B' as tab,B.* from B
                    ) t
            ) t

group by    t.r
           ,t.rn

-- having       count(*) = 2
;
```

---

```
+-------------+-------------+
| a_patientid | b_patientid |
+-------------+-------------+
| 3           | 5           |
+-------------+-------------+
| 2           | 6           |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 4           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

---

The main idea -

Rows from both tables are divided to groups by their attributes (race,gender).
This is being done using the RANK function.

Within each group of attributes (race,gender) the rows are being ordered, **per table**, by their patientid .

```
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| tab | patientid | race | gender |    | r | rn |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+

+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| A   | 1         | A    | F      |    | 1 | 1  |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| B   | 4         | A    | F      |    | 1 | 1  |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+

+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| A   | 3         | A    | F      |    | 1 | 2  |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| B   | 5         | A    | F      |    | 1 | 2  |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+

+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| A   | 2         | B    | M      |    | 5 | 1  |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
| B   | 6         | B    | M      |    | 5 | 1  |
+-----+-----------+------+--------+    +---+----+
```

In the final phase, the rows are being divided into groups (GROUP BY) by their RANK (r) and ROW_NUMBER (rn) values, which means each group has a row from each table (or only a single row if there is no matching row from the other table).

Comment: @onedaywhen, perhaps you didn't get it because it was actually wrong :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz This sounds intriguing - though we are missing how to see the match results. For example, Patient ID 6 should be matching patient ID 2. How do we see that match in the results table your SQL is generating? Oh wait - it appears you are matching pairs of rows? (1st row to 2nd row, 3rd row to 4th row)...etc.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Okay - I think we understand this now but there is one challenge - patients need to match *across* tables. It looks like in this approach patients in table A are being matched to patients in the same table (as opposed to being matched to patients in table B.) Is there a way to ensure that the matches occur across tables?

Comment: @Praxiteles, this is giving the requested results. The matches occur across tables. Check out the updated diagram

Comment: @Praxiteles, still here?

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, a lateral join would be the way to go.  In Google, you can use `row_number()`.  The query looks something like this:

```
select p.*, pp.patient_id as other_patient_id
from patients p cross join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col1) as seqnum
      from patients p
     ) pp
where pp.seqnum = 1;
```

The columns in the `partition by` are the columns used for similarity.

Comment: We just added sample tables to clarify the results for which we are aiming. Does your SQL still apply? The query is a bit mind-binding  on first read. Been researching to better understand lateral joins and your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.PatientID AS PatientID,
  b.PatientID AS PatientID_Match
FROM (
  SELECT PatientID, Race, Gender, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Race, Gender) AS Pos
  FROM TableA
) AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT PatientID, Race, Gender, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Race, Gender) AS Pos
  FROM TableB
) AS b
ON a.Race = b.Race AND a.Gender = b.Gender AND a.Pos = b.Pos
```

Above will leave out those patients from TableA which either do not have match in TableB or potential match in TableB was already used as match for another patient in TableA (as per your `we want pairs of patients so we cannot match a patient to more than one other patient.` requirement)

To address Dudu's comments about NULL for attributes:

```
SELECT 
  a.PatientID AS PatientID,
  b.PatientID AS PatientID_Match
FROM (
  SELECT 
    PatientID, IFNULL(Race, 'null') AS Race, IFNULL(Gender, 'null') AS Gender, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Race, Gender) AS Pos
  FROM TableA
) AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    PatientID, IFNULL(Race, 'null') AS Race, IFNULL(Gender, 'null') AS Gender, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Race, Gender) AS Pos
  FROM TableB
) AS b
ON a.Race = b.Race AND a.Gender = b.Gender AND a.Pos = b.Pos
```

Comment: This method doesn't handle null attributes

Comment: how null is relevant here? null as race? null as gender? patients with null attributes?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe not. If 2 records that are equale in some attributes and have nulls on the rest of the attributes, are considered a match by the OP, this solution won't handle them.

Comment: from how I understood OP use case - nulls should not be a case! At the same time it is easy to adjust the answer to handle null too! Will do if OP will ask. Thank you Dudu for checking :o)

Comment: There's a reason I didn't post an answer based on JOIN... :-) For the OP this might be fine but in various use-cases where NULLs do exist and the the type of the columns is varying (varchar, int, float, date etc.) handling NULLs become tedious and risky. The default value approach is dangerous since we have to guess/know the non-exist values.  .